# Vertically center only one of the divs within a parent div using fluid layout

Tags: html, css, centering, fluid-layout

I am trying to center text elements within a fluid layout, which means that sizes of `<div>` are not fixed.

I found a very nice solution for centering a child `<div>` inside a parent `<div>` both horizontally and vertically, and it works as: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tagqe/1/). (Originally from [the second method of this post](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/))

However, as shown in the fiddle, the `Large Text` element is not exactly positioned vertically at the center of the parent `<div class="block">`, instead, the whole child `<div class="centered">` is centered.

I tried breaking the two text elements into two separate `<div>`s, and centering the one which contains only `Large Text` element. However, it does not work as the second `<div>` containing `small text` gets pushed out of the parent `<div class="block">`

So how should I modify the current centering solution so that `Large Text` element is centered exactly within the parent `<div class="block">`, while still containing `small text` element just below the `Large Text` element?

Answer (score 0):

`vertican-align` was introduced to CSS as a replacement to the `valign` HTML attribute for tables. You'll note that `display:inline-block;` does not a table cell create and will not be trully centered with `vertical-align` at all. You could use `display:table` on the parent and `display:table-cell` on the child if you don't care too much about < IE8.

Other than the above, there is no quick and easy way to centre within a parent. However if you know the height of the element, you can use the old image placement trick on divs to.

```
<div>
    <p>Centred Text, Horizontal and Vertical</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
div {
    positon:relative;
    text-align:center;
    height:400px;
}

div p {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    top:50%;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tagqe/2/)

If this doesn't work for you, you can also position the `<p>` absolutely, though you would need to then center it horizontally without the assistance of text-align:center on the parent and display:inline-block on the child.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for an answer to this, I've made a demo:
http://dabblet.com/gist/3762377

Of course you would have to give the large text('.title' in my demo) a fixed height. 
Then pull the .box upwards using negative margin, with a value equal to .title's height.

The markup is:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="box">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;      
    text-align: center;
    }
    .container:before {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: -4px;
        }

    .box {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: 70px; /* Height of .title. In this case .title's line-height. */
        }
    .title {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;     

        line-height: 70px;/* This property could be either height or top,bottom padding. */ 
        }
```